# Get a random value from an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I have an array consisting of five values as such:

```
var myArray = ["Hi", "Hello", "Yes", "No", "10"]
```

I'm trying to get a value printed on random, so i've added this:

```
var rand = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];
```

But I'm unsure on where to put it. Anyone got better ideas on how to figure this one out?

Comment: where do you like to get the result?

Answer (score 2):

You could assign the random string to an element of DOM.

```js
var myArray = ["Hi", "Hello", "Yes", "No", "10"]
var rand = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];

document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = rand;
```

```html
<div id="out"></div>
```

Comment: @J.DoeFoe, you could [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) which help you most.